# If statement not checking multiple values

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, c#-4.0

I am trying to test and see if 4 user inputted answers are correct(I have tested without using if statements and all variables are correct), however it seems to only be checking 1 out of the 4 conditions in the if statement. I tried using both the single & and double && operator, and neither made a difference?

```
if(isOneCorrect.ToUpper() == checkBox1.Checked.ToString().ToUpper() && 
   isTwoCorrect.ToUpper() == checkBox2.Checked.ToString().ToUpper() && 
   isThreeCorrect.ToUpper() == checkBox3.Checked.ToString().ToUpper() && 
   isFourCorrect.ToUpper() == checkBox4.Checked.ToString().ToUpper())
   {
      MessageBox.Show("you won!");
   }
```

What can I do to make the if statement make sure EVERY condition of the 4 is correct?

Comment: what's the type of 'isOneCorrect' ?

Comment: I would try putting each of the four checks in their own set of parentheses `()` to start with

Comment: @ashin they are booleans

Comment: if they're booleans and not strings, then you could check isOneCorrect == checkedbox1.Checked instead of using ToUpper()?

Comment: @ashin I am convertinng them to a string and then capitalizing all text to avoid errors(it was another bug. Hard to explain.)

Comment: There's no need to cast a boolean to string.

Comment: @MichaelRoy Changing the data type won't fix the problem. Using booleans created a program earlier. It's how I am parsing the values.

Comment: Bad computer.  https://blog.codinghorror.com/the-first-rule-of-programming-its-always-your-fault/

Comment: How do you know its only checking 1 out of the 4 conditions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The boolean operators/expressions in C# shortcut - this means if you have several sequential boolean operators (like you have) then expression evaluation will stop when the overall result can no longer be changed.

So, to explain that a little more: you have four `&&` operators. For the `if` statement to valuate to `true` **all** of those ANDed expressions need to evaluate to true. If the first one fails there is no point evaluating the rest, the final result will not change.

When comparing strings you should use the [string.Equals()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.equals(v=vs.110).aspx) extension method.
However you did state in the comments that `isOneCorrect` is boolean; if `checkBox1.Checked` is also boolean then you do not need to convert anything to string, just compare the two booleans. If `checkBox1.Checked` is a nullable bool (bool?) then use the `HasValue` and `Value` properties to access it as a bool.